# Aptana Studio with XDebug: wrong file opened at breakpoint

Tags: debugging, zend-framework, aptana, xdebug

I'm using Aptana Studio 1.2.7 with XDebug 2.0.4 and my website is based on the zend framework. When reaching a breakpoint in my code, aptana studio opens the wrong file when there is more than one file with the same name (e.g. ..\library\Project\Db\Table\Abstract.php (breakpoint set) and \library\Zend\View\Helper\Placeholfer\Container\Abstract.php). The variables are shown correctly and the correct line is highlighted, the wrong file is shown. Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: Did you post this in the Aptana forums? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been resolved by installing Aptana Studio 1.5.1 and PHP Plugin 1.1. The IDE now opens the correct file and the remote debugger works much faster, too :)